# Ciphered and deciphered text don't match in php using aes algorithm

Tags: php

My code is as shown below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CardTransaction extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $tempToken = $request->token;
        $keyValuePair = $request->keyVal;
        $protectPayAPI = new ProtectPayApi();
$encryptedString = $protectPayAPI->setUtf8EncodeMd5HashTempToken($tempToken)
    ->encryptString(utf8_encode($keyValuePair))
    ->getEncryptedString();
$decryptedString = utf8_decode($protectPayAPI->setUtf8EncodeMd5HashTempToken($tempToken)
    ->decryptString($encryptedString)
    ->getDecryptedString());
         return response()
            ->json(['output' => $decryptedString]);
    }

}

class ProtectPayApi
{
    /* for temp tokens */
    private $_tempToken;

    /* md5 hash of utf8 encoded temp token */
    private $_md5HashUtf8TempToken;

    private $_encryptedString;
    private $_decryptedString;

    /**
     * @param string $tempToken
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUtf8EncodeMd5HashTempToken($tempToken) {
        $this->_tempToken = $tempToken;
        $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken = md5(utf8_encode($tempToken));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Encrypts the string using the set $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken
     * @param string $stringToEncrypt
     * @return $this
     */
    public function encryptString($stringToEncrypt) {
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC'));
        $this->_encryptedString = openssl_encrypt(
            $stringToEncrypt,
            'AES-128-CBC',
            $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken,
            0,
            $iv
        );
        return $this;
    }

    public function decryptString($stringToDecrypt) {
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC'));
        $this->_encryptedString = $stringToDecrypt;
        $this->_decryptedString = openssl_decrypt(
            $stringToDecrypt,
            'AES-128-CBC',
            $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken,
            0,
            $iv
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEncryptedString() {
        return $this->_encryptedString;
    }

     /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDecryptedString() {
        return $this->_decryptedString;
    }
}
```

Now my input `keyVal` is:

AuthToken=1f25d31c-e8fe-4d68-be73-f7b439bfa0a329e90de6-4e93-4374-863322cef77467f5&PayerID=2833955147881261&Amount=10.00&CurrencyCode=USD&ProcessMethod=Capture&PaymentMethodStorageOption=None&InvoiceNumber=Invoice123&Comment1=comment1&Comment2=comment2 &echo=echotest &ReturnURL=https://il01addproc.propay.com:443/Return.aspx &ProfileId=3351&PaymentProcessType=CreditCard&StandardEntryClassCode=&DisplayMessage=True&Protected=False.

But in the output I am getting is:

?m\t?q??\u000f?4?X?1c-e8fe-4d68-be73-f7b439bfa0a329e90de6-4e93-4374-863322cef77467f5&PayerID=2833955147881261&Amount=10.00&CurrencyCode=USD&ProcessMethod=Capture&PaymentMethodStorageOption=None&InvoiceNumber=Invoice123&Comment1=comment1&Comment2=comment2 &echo=echotest &ReturnURL=https://il01addproc.propay.com:443/Return.aspx &ProfileId=3351&PaymentProcessType=CreditCard&StandardEntryClassCode=&DisplayMessage=True&Protected=False\

Now is there anything missing because of that I am getting this only 95% matched string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the first block that is different and this is because the IV is different for encryption and decryption.

```
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC'));
```

[CBC Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) is self healing so the rest of the blocks are correct.

It is necessary to use the same IV on both encryption and decryption, in this code a new random IV is being created for both encryption and decryption.

One generally accepted method around this is to prefix the encrypted data with the IV, it does not need to be secret. Then on decryption split the IV and encrypted data and use that IV for decryption.